# How to find an unbiased estimator of $\mathsf{Uniform}(-\theta/2,\theta/2)$

Tags: probability, estimation, uniform-distribution, unbiased-estimator

How to find an unbiased estimator of $\mathsf{Uniform}(-\theta/2,\theta/2)$.
Is it a function of the order statistics?

Comment: It may help to start from writing the likelihood function and see what kind of estimator you get from it, and whether it is biased or unbiased

Comment: As asked the question makes no sense: the unbiased estimator need estimate a function of $\theta$ not the entire distribution.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and detail which steps you took to attempt to solve the question. Else the question risks getting closed.

Comment: Relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354893/sufficient-statistics-for-uniform-%ce%b8-%ce%b8

Answer (score 1):

$2\frac {N+1}N \mathrm{max}(|X_1|, |X_2|,...,|X_N|)$ where $N$ is sample size.

Suppose $X_i \sim U(-\theta/2, \theta/2)$.

Step 1: Let $Y_i = |X_i|$. What distribution does $Y_i$ follow?

Step 2: Find the distribution of $\mathrm{max}(Y_i)$. Refer [How do you calculate the probability density function of the maximum of a sample of IID uniform random variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample)

Step 3: Find the expectation of $\mathrm{max}(Y_i)$.

Then you find the answer.

Comment: Can u show me how it comes? Thank you.

Comment: I think it is self-study question, So I added the steps, instead of answers, in the Answer.