# Sufficient Statistic of Uniform $(-\theta,0)$

Tags: self-study, inference, uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_1, ... , X_n$  be i.i.d random variables  Uniform $(-\theta,0)$ , with $\theta > 0$ parameter

\begin{align}f_{\theta}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)&=\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i;\theta)
\\&=\frac{1}{(\theta)^n}\mathbf1_{-\theta<x_1,\cdots,x_n<0}
\\&=\frac{1}{(\theta)^n}\mathbf1_{(x_{(1)}\ge-\theta)}\mathbf1_{(x_{(n)}\le0)}
\end{align}

So can we conclude that the sufficient statistic for $-\theta $ so for  $\theta $ too is $X_{(1)}$.

Also that  the sufficient statistic for  $\theta $  is $-X_{(1)}$. ??

Thus,  both  $X_{(1)}$ and $-X_{(1)}$ are sufficient statistics for $\theta $ ?

Comment: Similar question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354893/sufficient-statistics-for-uniform-theta-theta

Answer (score 3):

As a function of $\theta$
$$
\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbf1_{x_{(1)}\ge-\theta}\mathbf1_{x_{(n)}\le0}=
\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbf1_{x_{(1)}\ge-\theta}
$$
Hence the likelihood function only depends on $X_{(1)}$, which makes it a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, $-\theta$, $\sin(3\theta)$ and any other function of $\theta$ (as sufficiency is not to be confused with unbiasedness or any other estimation property).

Comment: I don't understand that why we have $$
\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbf1_{x_{(1)}\ge-\theta}\mathbf1_{x_{(n)}\le0}=
\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbf1_{x_{(1)}\ge-\theta}
.$$ We have no restriction that $X_{i}(1 \le  i \le n)$ are non-positive  i.i.d random variables.

Comment: @Elisa: notice the introduction "As a function of $\theta$". The $X_i$'s are fixed and therefore negative.